# cursor is taking too long time to execute in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cursor

I am using cursor in mongo to iterate over 200k+ documents. It is taking more than 2 hours to process all those 200k documents. I am accessing my cursor like this.

```
const cursor = clientDBPool.collection('users').find({"ABC":2}).batchSize(1000);
for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {}
```

Is there any other approach which I can follow in order to speed up my process? I am doing this in NodeJs.

I tried using **for await of** loop but still it is taking 2 hrs.

```
 for await (const doc of cursor) {}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with node. Mongo shouldn't take much time for just 2L doc. Why do you have await? Is that causing the slowness?

Comment: @Gibbs as getting next batch using cursor.next() is asynchronous, that's why I used await there

Comment: What is a lakh document? You can use command monitoring to determine time spent in the database to execute each query/getMore.

Answer (score 0):

Look like cursor.forEach() is what you need.

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

callback = (data, index) -> 
  # do something here with data
cursor.forEach(callback);
```

You should process this kind of large process as a async job to make it faster.

But keep in mind that this kind of LONG PROCESS MAYBE make a unstable connection sometimes, so I'm searching for stable way to long process for now. (NOT SURE)